# How to Create Alert Dialog in ActionScript3?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-cs5

I'm working on a project with Actionscript 3.0 in Flash Pro (CS5). I want to create a confirmation box. If I were using the Flex SDK I could do this using the [Alert](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Alert.html) class in the **mx.controls** package. However, it seems that no similar control exists in the standard Flash library and any amount of Googling just leads me to Flex references.

Comment: You sound confused.  All Flex controls are built off ActionScript 3 and do not work in ActionScript 2 projects.  The mx.controls.Alert class is part of the Flex Framework and therefore ActionScript 3.  You never used that in an ActionScript 2 project.

Comment: I understand what he means since I have the same problem. In pure AS3 project mx.controls.Alert doesn't exist (but it does for a Flex project). I supposed it used to exist in AS2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this Class

```
package com.whatever {

//Imports
import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

//Class
public class AlertBox extends Sprite {

    //Vars
    protected var box:Shape;
    protected var yesBtn:Sprite;

    //Constructor
    public function AlertBox($:Rectangle):void {

        //Initialise
        box = new Shape()
        yesBtn = new Sprite()
        addChild(box)
        addChild(yesBtn)

        //Render
        with (box.graphics) {
            lineStyle(1)
            beginFill(0, 0.4)
            drawRect($.x, $.y, $.width, $.height)
            endFill()
        }

        with (yesBtn.graphics) {
            lineStyle(1, 0x00FF00)
            beginFill(0x00FF00, 0.4)
            drawRect($.x+$.width-100, $.y$.height-40, 80, 20)
            endFill()
        }

        //Events
        yesBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, yesClickHandler, false, 0, true) 
        yesBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, yesOverHandler, false, 0, true) 

    }

    //Handlers
    protected function yesClickHandler($):void {}
    protected function yesOverHandler($):void {}
```

Answer (score 2):

You said that you can't import mx.Controls in AS3 but the following should work in a flex 4 project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               creationComplete="init()">

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Alert;

        private function init():void
        {
            Alert.show("This is an Alert!!!");

        }// end function

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

</s:Application>
```

**[UPDATE]**

After realizing that I misunderstood the question, I looked on the internet for a Alert component for AS3 projects and found the following:

http://developer.yahoo.com/flash/astra-flash/alertmanager/

I'm going try my hand at creating a replica of the flex framework's Alert control and then update my answer again.

Comment: i didnt use .mxml file,i used .fla file so i Cannot import mx Controls in as3

Comment: @LeemaRose ah you want to use the Alert controls in a pure as3 project. Ok, give me a chance to change my answer.

Comment: i already saw that example and also i tried but i Cannot import com.yahoo.astra.fl.managers.AlertManager;

Comment: @Leema Rose did you copy the AlertManager component from the library of the downloadable [fla](http://developer.yahoo.com/flash/astra-flash/alertmanager/examples/SimpleASAlert.fla) to your fla's library?

Comment: If i Download and run the program it's working sir,but Seperately i cannot import com.yahoo.astra.fl.managers.AlertManager sir

Comment: @Leema Rose but did you copy the AlertManager component from the downloaded fla's library into your fla's library? If you don't know how, I can take screenshots of it and update my answer, but it's pretty simple.

Answer (score 2):

If your final swf is going to run in the browser and have script access, you could just use one of the [JavaScript PopUp Boxes](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp):

```
if(ExternalInterface.available) {

  if (ExternalInterface.call("confirm", "Should I trace 'Yes'?")) {

    trace("Yes"); // user clicked Okay

  } else {

    trace("User canceled or the call failed");

  }
}
```

I'm pretty sure this will freeze the Flash UI loop until the JavaScript function returns, so make sure you call it when it's all you want to be doing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can continue to use the same Alert class

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Alert.html